# Using jq to split

Tags: json, jq

New to jq. I am using it on windows command line. I need to split an array from the input JSON into rows and further split the element of the array into columns based on the tab delimiter (\t)

Example:

Input:

```json
{
  "ProcessId": "5452",
  "TotalRows": 226171,
  "Rows": [
    "001-CARDIO-GRAN\t1052",
    "01_MO_FIN\t1148",
    "02_MO_S_PACK\t1148"
  ]
}
```

I need:

```
GRAN,1052
01_MO_FIN,1148
02_MO_S_PACK,1148
```

I tried this:

```
jq-win32 "last(.[])" output.json
```

And got

```
GRAN\t1052",
"01_MO_FIN\t1148",
"02_MO_S_PACK\t1148",
```

How do I further pipe this to split to accomplish what I need.

Comment: Presumably you want `1052` rather than `t1052`. Also, see [how to format code (or JSON/XML etc.)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: oops that was a typo. Yes, "1052".  thats right. Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: What shell are you using? cmd? ps?

Comment: Why do you strip "001-CARDIO-" from the first value, but keep all others? What logic decides what to keep and what to remove?

Comment: I am using cmd.

Comment: the "\t" is the delimiter baased on which I always need to strip.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how it works on Windows, but on Linux, the following works:

```
jq -r '.Rows[] | split("\t") | .[0]+","+.[1]' < file.json 
001-CARDIO-GRAN,1052
01_MO_FIN,1148
02_MO_S_PACK,1148
```

It makes more sense to generate CSV instead which would double quote the strings:

```
jq -r '.Rows[] | split("\t") | @csv' < file.json 
"001-CARDIO-GRAN","1052"
"01_MO_FIN","1148"
"02_MO_S_PACK","1148"
```

Comment: In Windows the single quotes does not work and I replaced the outer single quotes to double quotes and it errors out as there is also inside double quotes which needs to be escaped and I cant figure out how to do that.

Comment: @RaghavKrishna On Windows, save the script in `script.jq` and run `jq -r -f script.jq < file.json`

Comment: @ikegami: `@csv` would quote the values, which the OP doesn't seem to want.

Comment: @ikegami: Included both options.

Comment: Yet another approach replaces tabs with commas: `jq -r '.Rows[] | gsub("\t"; ",")'`